# JHipster 500 error: "Cannot change session ID. There is no session associated with this request."

Tags: session, oauth-2.0, jhipster

I'm working with a JHipster application (generated with v3.4.2) and I occasionally get a server 500 error: `"Cannot change session ID. There is no session associated with this request."`
The application is configured to use OAuth 2.0 for security, and the session creation policy is set to `sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)`. The stacktrace does not go through my application code at all as far as I can tell.
My question:

- How do I make it so that my application does not attempt to change the session ID when it is configured to STATELESS?
- How can I prevent this error from happening?

Here is my `.yo-rc.json` file:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "3.4.2",
    "baseName": "xxx",
    "packageName": "xx.xx.xxx",
    "packageFolder": "xx/xx/xxx",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "oauth2",
    "hibernateCache": "hazelcast",
    "clusteredHttpSession": "hazelcast",
    "websocket": "no",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mariadb",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "buildTool": "gradle",
    "useSass": true,
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling",
      "cucumber",
      "protractor"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": [
      "en",
      "fr",
      "es"
    ]
  },
  "generator-jhipster-entity-audit": {
    "auditFramework": "custom"
  }
}
```

I also have the following JHipster plugins installed:

- jhipster-entity-audit - to track created & modified data for each entity
- jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer - to provide a REST endpoint for reindexing elastic

And finally, the stacktrace:

```
2016-09-21 02:42:59.057 ERROR 20379 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot change session ID. There is no session associated with this request.
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.changeSessionId(Request.java:2539)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.changeSessionId(RequestFacade.java:918)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.changeSessionId(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:249)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.changeSessionId(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:249)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor710.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:201)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.applySessionFixation(ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.java:55)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.AbstractSessionFixationProtectionStrategy.onAuthentication(AbstractSessionFixationProtectionStrategy.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy.java:89)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:98)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I had configured the app to use hazelcast for distributed session management, but then chose a stateless authentication method (oauth2) which caused my app to not have a session cookie, which led to the error describe above.

The solution was to comment out the generated code for initializing hazelcast session management, which was all of two lines.

In `CacheConfiguration.java`, I commented out the `"clustered-http-sessions"` line:

```
@Bean
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
    log.debug("Configuring Hazelcast");
    Config config = new Config();
    config.setInstanceName("CUE2");

    config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5701);
    config.getNetworkConfig().setPortAutoIncrement(true);

    // In development, remove multicast auto-configuration
    if (env.acceptsProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT)) {
        System.setProperty("hazelcast.local.localAddress", "127.0.0.1");

        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(false);
    }


    config.getMapConfigs().put("default", initializeDefaultMapConfig());
    config.getMapConfigs().put("com.ads.cue2.domain.*", initializeDomainMapConfig(jHipsterProperties));

    // vvv -- This line here -- vvv
    // config.getMapConfigs().put("clustered-http-sessions", initializeClusteredSession(jHipsterProperties)); <-- This line here
    // ^^^ -- -------------- -- ^^^

    hazelcastInstance = HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(config);

    return hazelcastInstance;
}
```

In `WebConfigurer.java`, I commented out the `initClusteredHttpSessions` line in `onStartup`:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    if (env.getActiveProfiles().length != 0) {
        log.info("Web application configuration, using profiles: {}", Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
    }
    EnumSet<DispatcherType> disps = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ASYNC);

    // vvv -- This line here -- vvv
    // initClusteredHttpSessionFilter(servletContext, disps); 
    // ^^^ -- -------------- -- ^^^

    initMetrics(servletContext, disps);
    if (env.acceptsProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION)) {
        initCachingHttpHeadersFilter(servletContext, disps);
    }
    if (env.acceptsProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT)) {
        initH2Console(servletContext);
    }
    log.info("Web application fully configured");
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate which class/code you commented out to resolve this? I'm also getting this error occasionally and want to get rid of it. Thanks.